# Oracle SQL - How to Select a substring index inside another Query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing a query that returns a bunch of things from multiple tables. The main query is against Table_1. I need to return a substring from a field in table 7. But I'm getting an error that Substring_Index is an invalid identifier. How can I achieve the intended result?

I have a field COLUMN_1 of TABLE_1 that has 3+ pieces of data, separated by " : " (space colon space) and I need to strip out the text before the first delimiter, and return the rest of it (regardless of length).

---

A simplified example:

```
SELECT t1.name
    ,t1.address
    ,t1.phone
    ,t2. fave_brand
    ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(t3.fave_product, ' : ', -1) AS Fave Product
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t2.brand_SK = t1.fave_brand_FK
INNER JOIN table_3 t3
    ON t3.product_list_SK = t1.fave_products
WHERE <a series of constraints>;
```

---

Please note, I am NOT normally an SQL developer, but the back-end dev is on vacation and I've been tasked with cobbling this fix together. I'm a beginner at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oracle you could use `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(t3.fave_product, '^[^:]*:', '') "Fave Product"
```

`regexp_replace()` replaces the part of the string that matches the regexp given as second argument with the value given as third argument. Here, we use the empty string as third argument, meaning that the matching part of the string is suppressed.

Regexp breakdown:

```
 ^       beginning of the string
 [^:]*   as many characters as possible other than ":" (possibly, 0 characters)
 :       character ":"
```

NB: identifiers that contain special characters (such as space) need to be double quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support `substring_index()`.  That is a MySQL function.

You can use `regexp_substr()`.  Without sample data it is a little hard to be 100% sure, but I think the logic you want is:

```
regexp_substr(t3.fave_product, '[^:]+$') as fave_product
```

Comment: I can't post the real data, but functionally it looks like:

customer name : industry : industry specialty

I need everything after the first " : " (i.e. everything except the customer name) 

Each fo the three data points all have variable character lengths.